# How to change from NSView subviews to CaLayers in a MacOs App?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, calayer, nsview

I have a music macOS Application that displays a piano roll with note events in a midi file. I am representing them as bars in a view, using a main NSView and a lot (typically 5000/10000) of subviews.This performs quite well, the only problem is on intensive tasks, like when I zoom the view, or I change the proportions from the GUI, I believe all the views receive a setNeedsDisplay message and resize accordingly. I was thinking,
Could I switch my implementation to CALayers instead of subviews ? the big NSView works in a NSScrollview. Perhaps I could try to implement some sort of lazy updating where only the visible notes get updated.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't see why you want to replace NSView subviews with CALayers.  Nonetheless, nobody has seen a single line of code.  So who knows!?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I could have posted some more details, but first of all, does 500/10000 views sound too high fora single NSView's subviews ?

Comment: I say Yes although I have done worse.  Once, I have created more than 10,000 NSButtons within a single view.

Comment: Can't you just draw your bars in the drawRect method of your view? 5000 views seems a lot… That way you could only update a specific part of the view with setNeedsDisplayIn(_ r: CGRect).